# Install Haskell (hugs) - Package not found

Tags: 10.10, installation, haskell

I have problems with installing haskell (hugs) on Ubuntu 10.10. I had the latest version before and I wrote just `sudo apt-get install hugs` and everything worked. But now with Ubuntu 10.10 It tells me that package hugs could not be found.

How can I install hugs then?

Comment: You say `sudo install hugs` Do you mean `sudo apt-get install hugs`?

Comment: yeah. sorry. and sudo apt-get install haskell-platform doesnt work as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to type `sudo apt-get install hugs` as the [Package does exist in 10.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/hugs) Alternatively you can download it from the Software Center